Azure Push Notification Hub for React Native
I am trying to implement azure push notifications in my react native app and testing it on android devices.
All the steps from creating the azure notification hub on azure, creating a firebase project and using the server key in azure are in place.
The issue that I am facing is when adding the dependency of the notification hubs in android/build.gradle:
This is android/app/build.gradle


apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"

/**
 * This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
 * By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
 */
react {
  /* Folders */
  //   The root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives. Default is '..'
  // root = file("../")
  //   The folder where the react-native NPM package is. Default is ../node_modules/react-native
  // reactNativeDir = file("../node_modules/react-native")
  //   The folder where the react-native Codegen package is. Default is ../node_modules/@react-native/codegen
  // codegenDir = file("../node_modules/@react-native/codegen")
  //   The cli.js file which is the React Native CLI entrypoint. Default is ../node_modules/react-native/cli.js
  // cliFile = file("../node_modules/react-native/cli.js")

  /* Variants */
  //   The list of variants to that are debuggable. For those we're going to
  //   skip the bundling of the JS bundle and the assets. By default is just 'debug'.
  //   If you add flavors like lite, prod, etc. you'll have to list your debuggableVariants.
  // debuggableVariants = ["liteDebug", "prodDebug"]

  /* Bundling */
  //   A list containing the node command and its flags. Default is just 'node'.
  // nodeExecutableAndArgs = ["node"]
  //
  //   The command to run when bundling. By default is 'bundle'
  // bundleCommand = "ram-bundle"
  //
  //   The path to the CLI configuration file. Default is empty.
  // bundleConfig = file(../rn-cli.config.js)
  //
  //   The name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
  // bundleAssetName = "MyApplication.android.bundle"
  //
  //   The entry file for bundle generation. Default is 'index.android.js' or 'index.js'
  // entryFile = file("../js/MyApplication.android.js")
  //
  //   A list of extra flags to pass to the 'bundle' commands.
  //   See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/commands.md#bundle
  // extraPackagerArgs = []

  /* Hermes Commands */
  //   The hermes compiler command to run. By default it is 'hermesc'
  // hermesCommand = "$rootDir/my-custom-hermesc/bin/hermesc"
  //
  //   The list of flags to pass to the Hermes compiler. By default is "-O", "-output-source-map"
  // hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
}

/**
 * Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
  ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
  buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
  compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

  namespace "com.azurenotificationhubpoc"
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.azurenotificationhubpoc"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  signingConfigs {
    debug {
      storeFile file('debug.keystore')
      storePassword 'android'
      keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
      keyPassword 'android'
    }
  }
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
      // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
      // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
      signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
      minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
  implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion"
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
  implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
  implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
  // Firebase Messaging
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.2.2'
  // Azure Notification Hubs
  implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:2.0.0'

  if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
    implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
  } else {
    implementation jscFlavor
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)



and this is android/build.gradle


buildscript {
   ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'  // Google Services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Ensure you have the following repsoitory in your "allprojects", "repositories" section.
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}



and this package.json:


{
  "name": "AzureNotificationHubPoC",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^19.2.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^19.2.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.7",
    "react-native-azurenotificationhub": "^0.9.5-Patched.1",
    "react-native-azurenotificationhub-mavencentral": "^0.9.5-Patched.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.73.21",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.73.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.73.5",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.73.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}



I am always getting the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-azurenotificationhub:generateDebugRFile'.


Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-azurenotificationhub:androidApis'.
Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported.


Try:


Switch Maven repository 'maven5(http://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols.
For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol in the Gradle documentation.
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 5s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-azurenotificationhub:generateDebugRFile'. > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-azurenotificationhub:androidApis'. > Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. *
Try: > Switch Maven repository 'maven5(http://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. > For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol in the Gradle documentation. > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 5s.
Can someone please tell me how can I solve this issue ? Could it be now that in react native I can no longer use react-native-azurenotificationhub ?

In the android/build.gradle file, locate the allprojects block within the buildscript block. Here's the relevant part of the android/build.gradle:
Code:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Ensure you have the following repository in your "allprojects", "repositories" section.
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


Update this block to include the correct repository URL for react-native-azurenotificationhub with HTTPS.

It should look something like this:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Ensure you have the following repository in your "allprojects", "repositories" section.
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK'
        }
        mavenCentral()
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
}


Replace the existing maven { ... } block with the updated one containing the HTTPS URL for the Azure repository.

NOTE: If possible, switch to a Maven repository that supports secure protocols (like HTTPS).

Alternative approach is to use the Azure Notification Hubs REST API directly from your React Native app. you can use the fetch API or a library like axios to make HTTP requests to the Azure Notification Hubs REST API endpoints.

const sendPushNotification = async (message) => {
  const hubName = 'YourNotificationHubName';
  const endpoint = `https://{your-namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/${hubName}/messages`;

  const requestBody = {
    data: {
      message: message
    }
  };

  const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `SharedAccessSignature ${yourSharedAccessSignature}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
  });

  if (response.ok) {
    console.log('Push notification sent successfully');
  } else {
    console.error('Failed to send push notification:', response.statusText);
  }
};

It is more flexibility and control over how push notifications are handled in your React Native app. it also requires more manual setup and implementation compared to using a dedicated library like react-native-azurenotificationhub.
Reference:

Azure Notification Hubs REST API - API endpoints, request and response formats, authentication, and more.

React Native fetch API - To make HTTP requests in modern JavaScript, including React Native apps.

React Native Push Notification libraries - While handling the client-side logic for receiving and displaying push notifications, you might find it helpful to use existing libraries react-native-push-notification.



Thanks alot for your answer. Regarding the alternative approach. Will I still be using Firebase in this case ? Are there any documentations or samples where this approach was used before ?

@user1997, yes you can use FC in the above case, please check the attached reference links for your requirement.

Thanks a lot for your answer. I see that you provided 3 links. Are those like 3 different approaches ? If I want to use React Native push notifications to receive a notification from azure notification hub so for example when I press test send I should receive the notification in the android emulator when my app is running. This is my objective. Should I create a new question for this ?

You're welcome! The links provided offer different types of resources to aid you in implementing push notifications with Azure Notification Hubs in React Native. They're not separate approaches but rather supplementary resources to support your implementation.
